# Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

```
SELECT IdAnnoucement, AnnoucementNAme, AnnoucmentDetails, DateOn, DateOff, 
active, appID FROM tblAnnoucemnt WHERE DateOn >= 
CAST(convert(nvarchar,CAST(GETDATE() as date))+'00:00:01') as datetime)) AND 
DateOff <= CAST(convert(nvarchar,CAST(GETDATE() AS date))+'23:59:01') as
datetime)) ORDER BY IdAnnoucement DESC
```

Comment: Please take a look at this guide on how to format your question so your code is readable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: Count the opening and closing `(` and `)`. Also, why are you converting a date/time to Unicode? And [without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)? And essentially using `BETWEEN` instead of >= today and < tomorrow (see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries))?

Comment: And finally, for good measure, your statement is [missing a terminating semi-colon](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx).

Comment: thank u all i will try to take your notice in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pay attention not only at the parenthesis, but also at the space bofe the `' 00:00...'`. This is needed in order to prepare the date to be converted properly.

```
SELECT idannoucement, 
       annoucementname, 
       annoucmentdetails, 
       dateon, 
       dateoff, 
       active, 
       appid 
FROM   tblannoucemnt 
WHERE  dateon >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(getdate() AS DATE)) + ' 00:00:01' AS DATETIME)
AND 
dateoff <= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(getdate() AS DATE)) + ' 23:59:01' AS DATETIME) ORDER BY idannoucement DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your parenthesis

```
SELECT  IdAnnoucement ,
        AnnoucementNAme ,
        AnnoucmentDetails ,
        DateOn ,
        DateOff ,
        active ,
        appID
FROM    tblAnnoucemnt
WHERE   DateOn >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + '00:00:01' AS DATETIME)
        AND DateOff <= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        + '23:59:01' AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY IdAnnoucement DESC
```